# Finding if a class template can be instantiated with a set of arguments, arity-wise (in C++17)

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

I have a template that takes a template template parameter and a pack of type arguments. I want to instantiate the template with the arguments only if the arities match. Something like this:

```
    // can_apply_t = ???

    template<template<typename...> typename Template, typename... Args>
    struct test {
        using type = std::conditional_t<can_apply_t<Template, Args...>, Template<Args...>, void>;
    };


template<typename> struct unary_template;
template<typename, typename> struct binary_template;

static_assert(std::is_same_v< test<unary_template, int>::type, unary_template<int> >);
static_assert(std::is_same_v< test<binary_template, int>::type, void >);
```

I fantasized that it would be as simple as this:

```
template<template<typename... T> typename Template, typename... Args>
struct test {
    using type = std::conditional_t<sizeof...(T) == sizeof...(Args), Template<Args...>, void>;    
};
```

...but clang++12 says:

> error: 'T' does not refer to the name of a parameter pack

Comment: `sizeof...(T)` would require a pack of types, not a pack of `class K,class V,...` (which doesn’t exist and can’t be deduced).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> fantasized that it would be as simple as this:

No... not as simple... when you write

```
using type = std::conditional_t<can_apply_t<Template, Args...>,
                                Template<Args...>,
                                void>;
```

the `Template<Args...>` must be an acceptable type also when test of `conditional_t` is false.

You need a `can_apply_t` that directly return `Template<Args...>` when possible, `void` otherwise.

I propose something as the following

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename... Ts>
auto can_apply_f (int)
  -> std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::declval<C<Ts...>>())>;

template <template <typename...> class C, typename... Ts>
auto can_apply_f (long) -> void;

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... Ts>
using can_apply_t = decltype(can_apply_f<C, Ts...>(0));

template <template<typename...> typename Template, typename... Args>
struct test {
  using type = can_apply_t<Template, Args...>;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++20, *concepts* will make things much easier.

```
template<template<typename...> typename, typename...>
struct test {
  using type = void;
};

template<template<typename...> typename Template, typename... Args>
  requires requires { typename Template<Args...>; }
struct test<Template, Args...> {
  using type = Template<Args...>;
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/aWdvMdnrj)

Comment: ...and so would many other things I am doing now in yomm2, but I want to keep compatibility with C++17 for a while.